# Laravel - Why middleware get skipped?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

Assume user have logged out and user visit this page `http://domain.com/admin`

In the controller, I have  `__construct` method like this:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth');
  dd("Hello World");
}
```

Why does it show "Hello World" on the screen? `$this->middleware` should be exectuted first and redirect to Login Page via auth middleware because User have not logged in.

However, If I remove  `dd("Hello World");` like this:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

It work fine and redirected to a login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$this->middleware` method actually binds your controller methods/actions to the `auth` middleware that you are defining. it doesn't executed at this point instead when your route gets called.

**Ref:** [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware)

> it is more convenient to specify middleware within your controller's
>   constructor. Using the middleware method from your controller's
>   constructor, you may easily assign middleware to the *controller's*
>   *action*.

and while hitting this route: `http://domain.com/admin`. In reality, your controller's `index` method fires after the controller object gets instantiated and binds the middleware.

Comment: Where can I see that `$this->middleware` bind to controller methods?

Comment: It is in the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container` class. Method name is `callClass`